# Unable to get to multiple username and password through a text file for java/selenium

Tags: java, selenium, text-files, java.util.scanner

I have a file which contains multiple usernames and passwords. I would like to access each of them by uniquely recognising the line 'Name:KYE-**N**APP', then take the username and password from the next 2 lines. I can currently only get the first username and password extracted. But when I enter 'Name:KYE-**APP**' i don't think it ever reaches there in the loop and I get an error **'Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Please enter a valid email address'** - Which i guess is from the browser.
}

Data text File
[image]

Code

```
public class SessionManagement {
    String name = "";
    String username = "";
    String passWord = "";

    public void login(WebDriver driver) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("src/main/resources/UserNames");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

        // test first line
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            name = scan.nextLine();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Name:KYE-APP")) { // name change to select the correct user and password

                username = scan.nextLine();
                WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("userName"));
                userName.sendKeys(username);

                passWord = scan.nextLine();
                WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
                password.sendKeys(passWord);

            

        }
        

        WebElement Submitbutton = driver.findElement(By.id("submitButton"));
        Submitbutton.click();
    }
        scan.close();
    }
```

Comment: you can set " unhandledPromptBehavior" as an option in the driver.   Set this to dismiss.  (It'll be triggered on the next action after the prompt is launched.)  By default the behavior is "dismiss and notify" which means it'll throw an exception.  In Chromedriver you set it to a constant: UnexpectedAlertBehaviour promptBehaviorConstant = UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.DISMISS; options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(promptBehaviorConstant);

Comment: but obviously the first problem here is that the site is expecting an e-mail address and you're not giving it a valid one.

Comment: So I need to catch the error and keep dealing with it until I get to correct line in the file?

Comment: You could, or just set the UnhandledPromptBehaviour to be "DISMISS"... (by default it's dismiss and notify which is why it's throwing... "notify" means throw an exception)

Comment: Seems like the UnexpectedAlertBehaviour is not available for Edge driver options.

Comment: seems to be the case at this point in time... I expect they'll add it since it is in the W3C webdriver spec... kind of odd because I think it is in the InternetExplorer driver.

Comment: Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); alert.accept(); inside a try catch should do it.

Comment: why don't you open  your browser when your ready with user id passwords .You can read it in one go store it hash maps or any suitable data structure  ..and then open browser and enter your data in loop..